# Trocar os espaços em branco por %20 no Java

Tags: java

Eu tenho a seguinte URL:

```
String Url = "www.minhaUrl/pagina/meus parametros tem espaços em branco";
```

Eu preciso transformá-la em:

```
String Url = "www.minhaUrl/pagina/meus%20parametros%20tem%20espaços%20em%branco";
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use o método

```
URLEncoder.encode("meus parametros tem espaços em branco", "UTF-8");
```

O [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) é o melhor jeito de se fazer isso já que você está mexendo com uma URL e ela vai tratar de qualquer outro caso necessário.

Comment: Este é o jeito correto de se tratar URL's, +1

Answer (score 4):

```
Url = Url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```